# spring mvc error de mime type

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, mime

hola que tal actualmente tengo un proyecto con las siguientes tecnologías

1. THYMELEAF
2. SPRING MVC
3. HIBERNATE
4. JPA

bueno al momento de generar una vista con css externo a que me refiero a que haga href hacia fuera del servidor .. no hay ningun problema

pero al momento de insertar un css ( que si lo carga ) pero manda este mensaje en la consola de google :

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/login' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir a la pregunta por lo menos el código donde estás insertando la hora de estilo?

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que para que thymeleaf pueda procesar correctamente estos archivos debes agregar la ruta segun su nomeclatura (th:href) dentro del HTML.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" 
      href="../../../css/gtvg.css" th:href="@{/css/gtvg.css}" />
```

Puedes revisar la documentación oficial. [Doc](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-the-value-of-any-attribute)